# Gcloud functions deploy with specific python file and specific function name

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy several Cloud Functions which are all in the same repository but in different python files.

Basically, I have those two functions

```
my_repo
- function_1_folder
  - function_1.py
  - requirements.txt
  - .gcloudignore
- function_2_folder  
  - function_2.py
  - requirements.txt
  - .gcloudignore
```

Inside `function_1.py` I have `function_1()` which I want to deploy to my cloud function called `function1` (note there is no underscore here), and same for `function_2`.

I go to `function_1_folder` and I have specified an entry point (`--entry-point function_1`) but I get a "missing main.py" error.

How can I specify both python filename and function name (if possible) ? Will gcloud also deploy the `requirements.txt` which is needed to install the packages my function depends on ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't name the source file arbitrarily. It's part of the [structuring requirements](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#structuring_source_code) that your Python source file should always be named `main.py`. This is how your directory should look like:

```
my_repo
 - function_1_folder
   - main.py
   - requirements.txt
   - .gcloudignore
 - function_2_folder  
   - main.py
   - requirements.txt
   - .gcloudignore
```

The flag `--entry-point` is used to specify the name of the function on your source file. For example (as HTTP):

**main.py**

```
def function_1(request):
    return 'Hello World'
```

Run this command inside `function_1_folder`:

```
gcloud functions deploy function1 --entry-point function_1 --runtime python37 --trigger-http
```

To answer your final question, requirements.txt is included along with your main.py and is a valid configuration. Those dependencies will be installed during build time.

As additional reference, see: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/functions

Comment: In addition to the 'main.py' you can have an arbitrary number of other python files (ie. 'file1.py', 'file2,py', etc.) in the same directory along with the 'main.py'. Those modules can be imported into (and used in) the 'main.py' in an ordinary way. On top of that any other files (i.e. json) in that directory can be used as well. Those file can be read (and used) from inside the code as ordinary files.